# How can I get the current URL in YAML?

Tags: yaml

I am trying to get the current location of my browser using YAML code, similar to the Javascript code "window.location.href". Is there a way to get the URL in YAML code?

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying to do?

Comment: YAML is a serialization language, not a programming language. There is no concept for "the current URL" in YAML.